# SecurityCenter WMI in Windows 8

Tags: powershell, wmi

Back in Windows 7 and older - I used a PowerShell script to access root\SecurityCenter or root\SecurityCenter2 in order to monitor AV/Anti-Spyware etc. via the `Get-WMIObject` cmdlet.

Now in Windows 8 onwards, this WMI Namespace no longer exists. I've done some research online I can't seem to find any alternative to easily access `Action Center` status for AV product, up-to-date status etc.

Does anyone know of anyway in Windows 8 to accces this info via PowerShell with similar results to old WMI method?

Comment: I just checked and the `SecurityCenter2` exist in Windows 8, this works for me
`Get-WmiObject -namespace root\SecurityCenter2 -class AntiVirusProduct`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the WMI namespace `root\SecurityCenter2` is still available in Windows 8.1, considering it's available in Windows 10 Tech Preview.

```
PS > Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\securitycenter2 -Class antivirusproduct

__GENUS                  : 2
__CLASS                  : AntiVirusProduct
__SUPERCLASS             : 
__DYNASTY                : AntiVirusProduct
__RELPATH                : AntiVirusProduct.instanceGuid="{D68DDC3A-831F-4fae-9E44-DA132C1ACF46}"
__PROPERTY_COUNT         : 6
__DERIVATION             : {}
__SERVER                 : MY-PC
__NAMESPACE              : ROOT\securitycenter2
__PATH                   : \\MY-PC\ROOT\securitycenter2:AntiVirusProduct.instanceGuid="{D68DDC3A-831F-4fae-9E44-DA132C1ACF46}"
displayName              : Windows Defender
instanceGuid             : {D68DDC3A-831F-4fae-9E44-DA132C1ACF46}
pathToSignedProductExe   : %ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\MSASCui.exe
pathToSignedReportingExe : %ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\MsMpeng.exe
productState             : 397568
timestamp                : Sat, 24 Jan 2015 20:53:02 GMT
PSComputerName           : MY-PC
```